# Not clear hashCode contract violation

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

What is the difference between two following scenarios:

1) override hashCode to return 1, don't override equals

2) override hashCode to return 1, override equals

EDIT:

A second case is well know - the performance of such map drops to that of LinkedList and it's O(n) instead of log(n). First case is more interesting. Contract is not clearly violated as confirmed by Eran, but this map won't work.

Comment: If everything has hashcode 1, then that is a valid but terrible hashcode, because everything of that type will always fall into the same hash bucket.

Comment: are you sure? Doesn't it make any difference how equals is implemented?

Comment: `hashCode` is a fast way of determining whether two objects are *not* equal: if their `hashCode`s don't match, you are saying that there is no way that they can be equal; however, this says nothing about whether they *are* equal.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are asking about using your class as a key in a `HashMap`.

In the first scenario, since `equals` is not overridden, `a.equals(b)` if and only if `a==b`. Therefore this implementation allows "logical" duplicates, since two distinct instances may have the exact same values for all their properties, but they are still not considered equal to each other.

In the second scenario, when `equals` is overridden, your implementation determines when two objects of the same class are equal to each other.

Both cases don't violate the contract of `hashCode`, but since `hashCode` always returns 1, both would have bad performance when serving as key in a `HashMap` or as element in a `HashSet`, since all keys would be mapped to the same bin, and the `HashMap\HashSet` would become a `LinkedList`.